# C#, when I maximize the form it moves to the top left

Tags: c#, winforms, maximize-window

When I maximize the form, the form is positioned in the upper left and does not grow. I designed the minimize, maximize and exit buttons that I use. I set `FormBorderStyle=None` and `FormStartPosition=CenterScreen`.

To maximize the window, I used the code `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`.

I should also say that I am calling the place where the user is logged in from another form.

These are the results I got:

**Normal**
[image]

**Maximized**
[image]

Comment: hi, perhaps this thread has some info https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fac1b44c-0b32-4d9a-8da2-7025a5f31bee/why-is-form-location-coordinates-44-when-form-is-maximized?forum=winforms

Comment: @jspcal That is normal for every maximized window with a system border. Maximized windows are actually moved slightly out of the screen and their content clipped, which was originally done to hide their resizable borders, same with the taskbar (to hide its Windows Classic 3D border).

Comment: I like your pretty colourful GUI! Most GUIs I've seen in WinForms are just dull, ugly grey or white forms! Good job with the graphic design!

Comment: Thank you Felix :) Krypton Framework is free on Github. You can download and licence is free .

Answer (score 4):

Check if the Form MaximumSize property is set to 0,0. If not set it to 0,0
then rebuild the project and test if it's working.

[image]

Comment: FormMaximumsize is already 0,0